# pt-kill not working for multiple line query

Tags: mysql, select, kill-process, percona

This is my below query, In the match-info in pt-kill, should be combined from starting and endpoint word of the Query. Not the SELECT only.

Here SELECT is **starting** word and **tn** is the ending word of the query.

Multiple line query

```
SELECT *
 FROM 
table_name
 as tn;
```

I have tried the below match-info, but it is working only a single line of the query.

'(^SELECT.+tn$)'

Please suggest the match info in pt-kill which should be combined of beginning and end of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` doesn't match newlines by default. Put `(?s)` at the beginning of the regexp to set the `dotall` flag to override this.

Also, there's a `;` at the end, you may need to include that in the match info.

```
(?s)^SELECT.*tn;$
```

Comment: It is worked without semicolon